# Can I develop a windows 8.1 app using visual studio 2013 in windows embedded 8.1 industry pro

Tags: .net, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-embedded

I have an account in Microsoft [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) for STUDENT, I have the opportunity to download and install

> Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro ([French link](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/fr-fr/windows-embedded-8-industry.aspx)) ([English link](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/windows-embedded-8-industry.aspx))

I would like to know if I can develop applications for Windows 8.1 using Visual studio 2013? What  features of Windows 8.1 Pro are not present in Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro? What is the problem to use this version of Windows knowing that I'm a developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most certainly use Visual Studio 2013 to develop applications for Windows 8, both "Metro"/"Modern UI" apps as well as native applications. However, Windows Embedded is not your standard, normal Windows version, but rather a version of Windows that's used on appliances like point-of-sale machines etc.

If you want to do normal Windows apps, don't bother with the embedded stuff.

Comment: i want to use windows for all development type ( metro style , web development , java , python, ..  ) , what is the problem to use an embedded version of windows ? can i do this using the embedded version ? i ask just because the embedded version is free for me as a student , microsoft student dreamspark not support the windows 8.1 pro , explain more please

Comment: @MedMans You can use Visual Studio for development for metro style apps, web apps and native with any of the supported languages (c#, visual basic, c++ or python for example). To do Java development you need another tool. Visual Studio (and also the "normal" Windows 8 Pro) are both available on Dreamspark and should be all you need. The embedded version is a really specialized version of Windows and not at all what you want or need. Get the normal Win 8 instead.